# decode bytes that are in string form with unkown encoding

Tags: python

So I just started my own little project to create a bot for a game, 
but only did little coding before, so I am definitely no expert, if I get something mixed up or forget to mention some information, I apologize in advance!

so basically my python bot will connect to the server (WebSocket connection 13, the header says "**Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br**"), I use the WebSocket module and that works well. the game sends messages in JSON format. however, they are filled up with backslashes, I think internally a javascript clears those out / splits each message into multiple ones and removes the outermost layer. so far my solution is to just clear out the backslashes and from there on it's pretty straightforward.

problem is: map data is apparently encoded. so basically the message would look like this:

```
{"type":"pkg","data":"[\"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"pl\\\",\\\"data\\\":[\\\"{\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"p\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\":227727,\\\\\\\"tpl\\\\\\\":227727,\\\\\\\"s\\\\\\\":458
```

.... and then at the end of the message (its a lot longer, i just didnt to post 30 lines of compressed data):

```
{\\\"type\\\":\\\"zip\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"{\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"map\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"xî182îyî478îtilesî\\\\\\\"1:î¢î¤î£î¦526_21î¢254
```

which is obviously the encoded / compressed map data. firefox dev tools however shows it decompressed too, it then looks more like this:

```
\\\\\\\"map\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"xî\u0080\u0086182î\u0080\u008dyî\u0080\u0086478î\u0080\u008dtilesî\u0080\u0086\\\\\\\"1:î\u0080¢î\u0080¤î\u0080£î\u0080¦526_21î\u0080¢254:36î\u0080²î\u0080´î\u0080³î\u0080µ:î\u0080¬î\u0080¸î\u0080ºî\u0080·î\u0080·î\u0080ºî\u0080¼î\u0080¶
```

I tried around with different commands and modules like `zlib`, but honestly, I m really lost. is that data already decoded and now in byte form or is that still compressed zip data? if so, how can I decode it, as I right now handle it as a raw string? or should I put it into a data file from the get-go? what does the xi, in the beginning, stand for, the encoding scheme?

any help is greatly appreciated, I would really like to know what the heck is going on here :D

Comment: Hard to give a definite answer on this one.

Do YOU have any idea what this map data is supposed to represent? When does it change?

What you are basically trying to do is reverse-engineer this protocol. It might not be 'encoded', it just might not be a string. They could be using those chars as byte values.

Either way those \u parts are probably unicode characters. It REALLY looks like they are just dumping a byte-stream into a field and encoding them as unicode. What I'd do is try to decode it as a unicode string, then treating it like a byte stream.

Comment: thanks for your answer! so the game is 2d - u can only move straight, not diagonally, simple x y coords. new map information only pops up, when there is an object on the map, if you run through just grass nothing happens. so generally i d just assume the output to be something like x:51, y:126, obj:xxx, list of objects is even in the first initial messages including the information if its destroyable / walkable.

Comment: Fair enough. Look you're at the point where all you can say is "at semi random times I get random bytes". There is no way to know whether any guess you have is true or not unless you take concrete steps from here on out.

A few ideas:
-Check to see if anyone else has parsed\written code for the data you are receiving.
-Spoof data to your client (way easier said than done). How does your client react with fake data?
-Load the client into IDA and have fun (assembly is rarely fun)

Comment: From the outter perspective the data looks like over-encoded JSON, where lower layers are JSON encoded strings again. This will be rather painful to decode layer for layer. The last chunk of data you posted looks like UTF-16 or a similar encoding. To cut the long story short: whoever encoded the data did not have any experience with JSON.